# Identify window without title

Tags: windows-10, office365

Often when I turn on my pc (from hibernation) I see a window flashing on the screen for 1-2 minutes. It's very fast, so I can't see anything about it, even recording my screen shows only a blank window.

It's like the Office 365 login window wanting to be shown but had to restart continuously. After a while it disappears and everything works fine.

Today I was "lucky" enough and the process failed, I see below window, so I can make a bit more investigation to learn what is it exactly.

I've just realized it's a popup of Outlook as I can't use Outlook while the window is open.

Unfortunately this window is not shown in app list when I press Alt+tab or Win+tab, and I don't know what to look for in task manager.

How can I identify the process showing me this error? and how to prevent it from happening again?

The window is still open, however if I close it I'll be able to get it in several weeks and until then it'll just annoy me with flashing.

[image]

(HP EliteBook 850 G7 with Windows 10 1909 (18363.1916) and Office 365 for Enterprise version 2102)

Comment: What kind of identification are you looking for? Do you want to know which process it belongs to? Process Explorer can do that. Do you want to know what’s the original purpose of the window? That might be impossible to find out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of issues, so I don't know what is exactly needed for troubleshooting, just want to prevent this window flashing 1-2 minutes almost each time I turn on my computer. What do you mean by process explorer? is it a standalone tool? How I can identify the culprit from the 100+ processes running?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Process Explorer = https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: The window belongs to Outlook. You don't need Process Explorer to figure that out, just enter the error into google. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef65a6c0-6f4a-497b-913f-d55d4a42aa7a/outlook-8220we-are-unable-to-connect-right-now-please-check-your-network-and-try-again?forum=outlook Has a couple of solutions. If you use Cisco Umbrella and the roaming client look at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2329510-we-are-unable-to-connect-right-now-please-check-your-network-and-try-again-late

Comment: Please make sure "Network Location Awareness" service is in Running status.